# Add components dynamically in rivets.js not working

Tags: javascript, rivets.js

I get the data from server and loop the data value 
then I will add the rivets template in HTML DOM according to the data

**this is my HTML code**

> ```
> <div rv-each-mod='not.module'>
>     <div rv-templatemod="mod"></div>
> </div> 
> <template id="h_title">
>   <div class="notice-tp notice-i">
>     <p class="notice-tp-t first_font_size second_color">{modinfo}</p>
>   </div>
> </template>
> ```

**this is my javascript code**

> ```
> function templateViewModel(attributes) {
>    this.modinfo= attributes.modAttr;
>    console.log(this.modinfo)
> }
> rivets.binders.templatemod = function(el, mod) {
>    var element=document.createElement(mod.type);   //example mod.type = htitle
>    element.setAttribute("mod-attr",JSON.stringify(mod))
>    el.parentNode && el.parentNode.appendChild(element)
> }
> rivets.components["htitle"] = {
>     template : function (){
>        return $api.html($api.dom("#h_title"));
>     },
>     initialize: function(el, attributes) {
>         return new templateViewModel(attributes);
>     }
> }
> rivets.bind($api.dom("#rivets-bind"),{
>     not:notice
> })
> ```

When I run it in chrome I found that htitle tag is created but template is not add why?

this is code in chrome debugger

> ```
> <h_title mod-attr="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;htitle&quot;,&quot;content&quot;:&quot;xxxxxx&quot;}"></h_title>
> ```

it should be

> ```
> <h_title mod-attr="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;htitle&quot;,&quot;content&quot;:&quot;xxxxxx&quot;}">
>     <div class="notice-tp notice-i">
>         <p class="notice-tp-t first_font_size second_color">{modinfo}</p>
>     </div>
> </h_title>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I use [rivets-include](https://github.com/der-On/rivets-include) to achieve it